# 504 gateway timeout - php

Tags: php, api

I'm calling an api using file_get_contents which is rather sporadic, sometime the call returns data really quickly (1-2 seconds) at other times takes a bit longer (30 seconds plus) leading to a 504 gateway timeout, here is the header return:

"Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 504 GATEWAY_TIMEOUT [1] => Content-Length: 0 [2] => Connection: Close )”

I've tried setting - set_time_limit(0); however this doesn't seem to have any effect, is there any other way to stop this timeout happening, i.e. wait longer to get a return from the api?

Cheers,

Matt

Comment: The server to whom you are sending request is taking too much to process data you are sending him, its not on your side. You need to increase timeout at server

Comment: Do i increase time out limit on my server, if so do you know how i do this, my server is linux centos running php?

Comment: What server are you using? apache? nginx?

Comment: apache, using whm and cpanel

Comment: IS your request working something with database? if so, which one do you use?

Comment: I'm storing data in a mysql database, I've changed max-execution-time and max-input time in php.ini to 360 seconds but timeouts still occur after around 30 seconds. The script runs on a webpage that is loaded in the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding 504 error, either is php taking too long to process the script or your database process large query. As discussed in comments, it seems like it is MySQL timeout.

What you gonna do is to increase timeout in my.cnf (which is MySQL configurational file) and change this line of code `wait_timeout` to some reasonable value, lets say 28000.

That should do it.